# @font-face not working in Android browsers

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, font-face

The following `@font-face` declarations work fine in in every major browser `(including Chrome for Android)` except for the `Android Browser` and `Firefox for Android` (from http://oftn.org/css/global.css):

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "OFTN Aller";
        src: url("../fonts/OFTN-Aller-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
             url("../fonts/OFTN-Aller-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
        font-family: "OFTN Aller";
        src: url("../fonts/OFTN-Aller.woff") format("woff"),
             url("../fonts/OFTN-Aller.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

### Screenshots

**Android 4.0.3 browser:**

[image: Screenshot of oftn.org]

**Chrome 19 on Windows 7:**

[image: Screenshot of oftn.org]

**Firefox 13 on Windows 7:**

[image: Screenshot of oftn.org]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subset OFTN Aller (bold) more since I'm not using it for other headers any more (only the logo) and that seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

.woff is not supported in android

check
[font support](http://caniuse.com/woff)

Edit: i think the page is loading correct because it looks same on desktop.

```
Our Name
ΩF:∅ means "ohm-farad to none", and we usually pronounce it as "often".
```

Comment: Which is why I include a TrueType font as well… I'll include a screenshot of major browsers for comparison.

Comment: try to load it with only truetype. remove .woff for checking.

Comment: I did that previously and it made no difference.

Comment: it should work. Maybe could you try with a fontsquirrel random font to check your own is not corrupted or broken someway ?

Comment: try removing .woff and load on other platforms to see truetype is working correctly.